# VS 2010 navigation bar is missing - how to proceed?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've used Visual Basic for almost 20 years, I think, starting with VB6. I've been using VS 2010 since, well, 2010, and have never had this problem before: The navigation bar in the Basic editor has disappeared.

Every solution I have found online says to go to Options->Text Editor->All Languages and enable navigation bar. As the attached screen caps will show, this is confirmed, but it's still not showing.

[image: VB Options][image]

It only does this for this one asp.net project I am working on. For all other current VB projects the navigation bar is visible. Also, on the .ASPX editor on this project the navigation bar is visible.

I closed all projects, all programs and even restarted the computer, no luck.

So I guess it's a two-part question: what do I do to restore the navigation bar? And if I can't restore it, is there an alternative to creating methods for object events?

Thanks!

Comment: "is there an alternative to creating methods for object events?"   If it's a control that shows up in Design View, there is one way.  You can select the control in Design View and go to the Properties window.  You can then click the yellow lightning bolt, select the correct event and press <ENTER>.

Comment: Try opening the settings file "...\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings".  What does your "Basic" "ShowNavigationBar" say?  Mine actually says 'false'.  The Basic checkbox is NOT CHECKED for me, but the navigation bar shows up just fine!  Maybe the problem is that your setting was actually set to True, but it shouldn't be for VB?  I think VB's nav bar is different, and that's why the option to toggle it is disabled :-/

Comment: @Snooker, it seems to be unique just to this one project; in other projects the navigation bar shows fine. I would assume that the CurrentSettings file would be for global use. At any rate, it's a moot point now because I just started a new project and imported all of that project's files. A few slight changes, and everything's good now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the first image for "All Languages" that you posted, your checkbox is just blue.  You need to check the box once more until you get a check mark. Having a checkbox filled with blue is not confirmed.

Here's an example of what it should look like.
[image]

Comment: Blue just means it's selected for some children and not for others.

Comment: Thanks, but still no go.